# Docker on mac --add-hosts option isn't really adding the host

Tags: docker, hosts, docker-network

I have docker 1.12.3 running on macOS sierra.

I need my server to set serveral ips in the hosts file, and also set the containter hostname to resolve to 127.0.0.1.

I had the following command

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 --add-host someServer:192.168.1.1 --add-host myHostName:127.0.0.1 -h myHostName myImage
```

So the hostname did changed to myHostName, and also added to the hosts file. 
However, it doesn't do anything!. Trying to use it in my server, or even just do ping myHostName resolve in

```
ping: unknown host
```

From the documation it look like it should work, but it doesn't. I really need it and I don't have any more ideas how to solve it.

Please help.

Comment: But does not the `--add-host` flag add additional `/etc/hosts` entries to the container and not your client? So you should add `127.0.0.1 myHostName` to you `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. I did add myHostName to the hosts file. with  "--add-host myHostName:127.0.0.1"

Comment: This only adds the hostname to the  /etc/hosts file in the container not your client.

Comment: @Cyclone I know, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. The ping to the hostname isn't working from inside the container - as if the changes in the hosts file didn't really happend